# Is there a way to remove the ACCOUNT editing the styles.css?

Tags: magento-1.9

Is there a way to remove the ACCOUNT editing the styles.css?  The ACCOUNT at the top of the page.  I don't know how to edit the .xml files.  I'm a total novice! Thanks,
                                                     -John

Comment: What do you exactly want to do? The is a link near cart in header. And probably you want to move/hide/add another stylization to it?

Comment: I just want to remove that link and the person icon.  Thanks, -John